# amazon s3 InvalidRequest error in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
var s3 = require('s3');
var client = s3.createClient({
maxAsyncS3: 20,    
s3RetryCount: 3,   
s3RetryDelay: 1000, 
multipartUploadThreshold: 20971520, 
multipartUploadSize: 15728640,
s3Options: {
 accessKeyId: "ABC",
  secretAccessKey: "XYZ",
  region: " us-east-2",
  endpoint: 's3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
  ACL: ''
  }
 });
  var uploadParams = {
    localFile: '/home/onur/Desktop/cwiz.jpg',
    s3Params: {
        Bucket: 'cwizz',
        Key: '', // How can I found bucked key ?

    }
};

var uploader = client.uploadFile(uploadParams);

uploader.on('error', function(err) {
  return console.error('unable to upload:', err, err.stack);
});
uploader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done uploading");
});
```

How can I found bucked key ?

unable to upload: { InvalidRequest: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: There is a stray space inside the quotes, here: `region: " us-east-2",`

Answer (score 0):

Bucket key is the path inside the bucket where you want your file to be uploaded. e.g. the following will upload your image to images/cwiz.jpg inside the cwizz bucket. Also, you don't need region, endpoint and ACL in the s3Options object.

```
var s3 = require('s3');
var client = s3.createClient({
maxAsyncS3: 20,    
s3RetryCount: 3,   
s3RetryDelay: 1000, 
multipartUploadThreshold: 20971520, 
multipartUploadSize: 15728640,
s3Options: {
 accessKeyId: "ABC",
  secretAccessKey: "XYZ"
  }
 });
  var uploadParams = {
    localFile: '/home/onur/Desktop/cwiz.jpg',
    s3Params: {
        Bucket: 'cwizz',
        Key: 'images/cwiz.jpg',

    }
};

var uploader = client.uploadFile(uploadParams);

uploader.on('error', function(err) {
  return console.error('unable to upload:', err, err.stack);
});
uploader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done uploading");
});
```